# give a counterexample that shows $X_n/\sqrt{ n}$ need not converge to zero with probability one

Tags: real-analysis, probability

You have a sequence of (possibly dependent) random variables ${X_n}$
defined on the probability space $(Ω,F,P)$, and you are given that
$$
EX_n^2\leq1\quad for~all ~n\geq1
$$

First, give a counterexample that shows $X_n/\sqrt{ n}$  need not converge to zero with
probability one. Second, show that if the $X_n$  all have the same distribution (though
still possibly dependent) then $X_n/\sqrt{ n}$  does converge to zero with probability one.

I really need some ideas to help me start out. Thank you!

Comment: So that bound makes it so $X_n $ can't be too far away from zero with too much probability. So now consider just a case where $X_n $ is either zero or some other value. How big can that other value be, and how probable can it be? (Of course those questions go together: you can make the value bigger by making it less probable. But there is a particular useful choice of the value...)

Comment: I have tried sth like $P(X_n=n)=1/n^2$ and $P(X_n=0)=1-1/n^2$ but not works..

Comment: Think about the Borel-Cantelli lemma. If you have $P(X_n=M_n)=p_n,P(X_n=0)=1-p_n$, and $\sum p_n$ converges, then the probability that $X_n=M_n$ infinitely many times is zero. Hence the sequence goes to zero a.s. But if $\sum p_n$ *diverges* then this no longer occurs necessarily. In your attempt the sum converges. Can you tweak your numbers so that it diverges and also $M_n/\sqrt{n}$ doesn't go to zero? Once you've done that it's just a matter of getting the dependence chosen just right.